How to make sense of the variational derivative?
In most derivations of the Euler-Lagrange equation, the action is fed a function with some arbitrary variation delta times a degree of variation epsilon, and the action goes from being a functional to now being a function of a single variable epsilon, and then we can take the derivative with respect to epsilon to recover the E-L equation. But in the picture, the derivative is not with respect to epsilon, but with respect to the arbitrary variation, which I can't see how to rigorously justify that.


In the Calculus of Variations you define a concept of variation of a functional, akin to the concept of differential of a function of several variables. For a (smooth) function of several variables, its differential at a point $x$ and a variation of $x$ given by ${\mathbf dx}= (dx_1,dx_2,\dots dx_n)$ is a linear function of ${\mathbf dx}$ (possibly non-linear in $x$, $L(x,{\mathbf dx})=A_1dx_1+A_2dx_2+\dots A_ndx_n$ such that
$$
\Delta f=f(x+{\mathbf dx})-f(x)=L(x,{\mathbf dx})+ negligible,
$$
the negligible part containing quantities that approach zero faster than ${\mathbf dx})$ as the latter goes to zero. Then the $A_i$ are unique, they are called partial derivatives, etc.
In the Calculus of Variation the situation is similar. Now you have a functional $\mathcal{L}(y)$ depending on a whole function $y(x)$, a continuum of values (as opposed to $n$ real arguments $(x_1,x_2,\dots x_n)$ as before) and you define the variation of $\mathcal{L}$ at $y$, corresponding to a variation $\delta y(x)$, as a linear functional $\delta\mathcal{L}$ of $\delta y(x)$ that represents the principal part of the increment of $\mathcal{L}$. That is,
$$
\Delta\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}(y+{\mathbf\delta y})-\mathcal{L}(y)=\delta\mathcal{L}+ negligible,
$$
with the same meaning.
Linear functionals of $\mathbf\delta y$ appearing in the Calculus of
Variation, where you look at a certain type of variational problems, are given by integrals
$$
\delta\mathcal{L}(y,\delta y)=\int\limits_a^bG(x,y(x),y'(x))\mathbf\delta y
$$
as your computation shows. The function $G$ is the left hand side of Euler-Lagrange equations, and is a continuous analog of partial derivatives, whereas the integral is analog to the differential. Setting $G=0$ this time gives you a differential equation instead of algebraic equations in the case of several independent variables.

Actually, there exist various generalizations of the derivative, depending on the considered functional spaces, that is why you may encounter several (more or less equivalent) definitions of the functional derivative / differential.
The most basic one corresponds to Fréchet derivative, given by the linear functional $\delta J[y] = J[y+\phi] - J[y]$, with $\|\phi\| \to 0$, but it may not exist or be ill-defined. In particular, the result might depend on the "direction" $\phi$, analogously to non-differentiable bivariate function $f(x,y)$ you have propably encountered in classical calculus.
This notion of functional differential is usually relaxed by considering Gâteaux derivative, which is nothing else than a directional derivative along a continuous curve $\epsilon\phi(x)$, with $\epsilon \to 0$, i.e.
$$
\delta J[y] = \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{J[y+\epsilon\phi]-J[y]}{\epsilon} = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon=0} J[y+\epsilon\phi].
$$
You can compare this definition to the directional derivative of multivariate function in classical calculus, whis is given by $\nabla_\mathbf{v}f(\mathbf{x}) = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0} f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla_\mathbf{x} f(\mathbf{x})$. Then, the stationary points of $J$ are those where its functional derivative vanishes, which is equivalent to a vanishing directional derivative in every directions, that is why the function $\phi$ is usually said to be arbitrary.
Finally, if your functional is smooth enough and its Gâteaux derivative doesn't depend on the considered direction, as it is usually the case with linear functionals such as the integrals of Lagrangian mechanics, the functional differential can redefined naively in the same way as in classical calculus, by treating $J$ as a multivariate function of $y$ and its derivatives, hence $\delta J[y] = \frac{\partial J}{\partial y}\delta y + \frac{\partial J}{\partial y'}\delta y' + \ldots$ and the kind of expressions displayed on your picture. It is to be noted that this last approch, when doable, is equivalent to Gâteaux derivative, because $\delta y = \phi\,\mathrm{d}\epsilon$ actually.

It’s worth noting that one extra structure is needed to fully recover the Euler-Lagrange equation. You need an inner product and the Reisz representation theorem or some sort of duality pairing to derive a gradient from the derivative map. We typically use $L^2$ inner product and setting this gradient equal to zero yields the E-L equation
